# How to find min max from lm

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out a way to find the minimum/maximum from a fitted quadratic model. In this case the minimum.

```
x.lm <- lm(Y ~ X + I(X^2))
```

Edit: To clarify, I can already find the minimum y through min(predict(x.lm)). How can I translate this to it's corresponding x value.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.

Comment: Some [basic highschool maths](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Maximum-or-Minimum-Value-of-a-Quadratic-Function-Easily) allows you to calculate this from the coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out. Idea is that you have to take fitted values form x.lm fit

```
#example data

X <- 1:100 
Y <- 1:100 + rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 4)

x.lm <- lm(Y ~ X + I(X^2))

fits <- x.lm$fitted.values #getting fits, you can take residuals,
# and other parameters too

# I guess you are looking for this.
min.fit = min(fits)
max.fit = max(fits)
```

## After another question

```
df <- cbind(X, Y, fits)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
index <- which.min(df$fits) #very usefull command
row.in.df <- df[index,]
```

Comment: This gives me the lowest y for the curve. What about using the min(x.lm$fitted.values) to find the corresponding x value?

Comment: I upgraded my answer. Ofcoruse you don't need to cbind X, Y and fits into one data frame. You just need to get the index by the funtction which min, or max, and by this index you have coresponding number from X, your.desired.min <- X[which.min(fits)]

Comment: Thanks. That came very close to a manual method I performed to find the answer.